# How to update WDA WebDriverAgentRunner product build version?

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook

I am currently using Facebook WDA to run some automation testing on my app and adding some custom methods in it to gain additional functionality. I am trying to maintain the versioning of the updates. However I am not able to find the product build version getting set anywhere in the source code or build settings.It seems like WebDriverAgentRunner product configuration are not getting set by its target. It always gives 1.0 in the product .plist as displayed in the screenshot below.

[image]

I would really appreciate some help on it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

`Facebook/WebDriverAgent` does not make releases by updating their versions. They just tag their releases.

please find the snapshot of their release history below.

[image]

Please find their Release page [here](https://github.com/facebook/WebDriverAgent/releases).

So, it's always going to be 1.0.

If you want to maintain the version every time you upgrade, you can just do it by updating the `Info.plist` yourself manually. That's the only place where version can be maintained.

Comment: I tried to update it manually but then  package doesn't get verified and gives an error while installing.

Comment: Can you please give me some more details on error you are getting? Snapshot if any ?

Comment: It doesn't install the WDA on the device if I update the info.plist. I am using Quamotion manager to install the WDA on device.